# Get list of full installed updates in PC

Tags: c#, command-line, dos, wmic, qfe

I tried to get list of full installed updates in my pc using following command.

> wmic qfe list

But I got only windows updates,

Can you tell how to get list of full updates?

like

> contorl panel -> Installed Updates

Code will in c# or Command line.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bece1e5d-0d5a-44c2-85c8-a23633d69388/how-to-retrieve-windows-installed-updates-through-resigtry-using-c?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: @Senthilkumar Here too we are getting only windows updates, I need all updates.

Comment: read the content full, this registry based we get all installed application updates

Comment: So only possible is save already and compare with latest right?

Comment: ok give the answer, I will mark as answer

Comment: do you have any knowledge in smart card , i have some doubts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64781/discussion-between-vikram-bose-and-senthilkumar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below link help with you: 
 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bece1e5d-0d5a-44c2-85c8-a23633d69388/how-to-retrieve-windows-installed-updates-through-resigtry-using-c?forum=csharplanguage